# Counter not working right, counting one for two

Tags: python

My counter isn't counting the keywords as many time as they are typed. Please tell me what's wrong.

```
Input: while while
output: while: 1
```

```
phrase = input('Enter Python source code:').split(' ')
counter = 0
keywords = {"and", "del", "from", "not", "while",
                "as", "elif", "global", "or", "with",
                "assert", "else", "if", "pass", "yield",
                "break", "except", "import", "print",
                "class", "exec", "in", "raise",
                "continue", "finally", "is", "return",
                "def", "for", "lambda", "try"}
dict1 = {}
for x in phrase:
    if x in keywords:
        dict1[x] = counter
        if x in dict1:
            dict1[x] += 1
        else:
            dict1[x]=1

sorted_dict= dict(sorted(dict1.items()))
for x in sorted_dict:
    print(x,':',dict1[x])
```

Comment: You do `dict1[x] = counter` every time you find a keyword, overwriting whatever value was in the dictionary before with zero.

Comment: And that line is wholly pointless; the rest of the code already handles the case where the key doesn't exist yet.

Comment: PS - since you're still accessing the original dictionary in your `print()`, you might as well just use `for key in sorted(dict1)`. Dictionaries provide their keys as iterators. Calling `items()` and creating a new "sorted" dictionary is wasteful when all you need are the keys in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been explained in the comments, so I'll only post a suggested solution:

```py
from collections import Counter
from keyword import kwlist


keywords = set(kwlist)
phrase = input('Enter Python source code: ').split()
d = Counter(word for word in phrase if word in keywords)
```